# Chain of functions for variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, opengl, variadic-templates

I am trying to design a generic, type-safe way to load interleaved data into a OpenGL VBO. My problem is now how to organize the various glVertexAttribPointer() calls. I have defined the buffer data descriptor as follows.

```
template <typename T>
struct Descriptor
{
    T vertex;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Descriptor
{
    T vertex;
    U normal;
};
...
```

This is basically now all well and simple. However, my problem is that the template functions to actually set the attributes turned out as follows.

```
template <template <class> class Desc, typename T>
void setAttributes(const Desc<T>& desc)
{
    // set attributes for vertices
    ...
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, sizeof(desc.vertex), ...);
}

template <template <class, class> class Desc, typename T, typename U>
void setAttributes(const Desc<T, U>& desc)
{
    // set attributes for vertices
    ...
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, sizeof(desc.vertex), ...);
    // set attributes for normals
    ...
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, sizeof(desc.normal), ...);
}
...
```

Basically the problem is that I still ended up with a lot of repetition. Is there a way break these down into two template functions where one only sets vertex attributes and one sets only normals? In pseudocode something like the following.

```
template <class Desc, class T, Args...>
void setAttributes(Desc desc)
{
   setVertexAttributes(...);
   // somehow decide that if there are args left, call again...
}

template <class Desc, class U, Args...>
void setAttributes(Desc desc)
{
   // ...ending up here
   setNormalAttributes(...);
}
```

Comment: I have been through this in the past trying to make the most efficient generic vertex stream specification and I've come to the conclusion it's premature pessimisation.  The approach I take now is to create a set of structures that describe each attribute and I iterate them, similar to what you might do describing a vertex in DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> This is basically now all well and simple.

What you have before that statement is not well.

```
template <typename T>
struct Descriptor
{
    T vertex;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Descriptor
{
    T vertex;
    U normal;
};
```

is invalid C++. You can't have a class template overloaded like that. You can do something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct Descriptor
{
    T vertex;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Descriptor<std::pair<T, U>>
{
    T vertex;
    U normal;
};
```

or

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Descriptor
{
    T vertex;
    U normal;
};

template <typename T>
struct Descriptor<T, int>
{
    T vertex;
};
```

Since I don't understand how you intend to use them, I can't tell which one will be a better fit for your needs.

Comment: Ah, true. After thinking a bit, I think std::tuple<T>, std::tuple<T,U>, ... is basically the same thing I was trying to achieve with Descriptor. Nevertheless, rest still stands.